# Simple python curses-application uses 100% CPU while running. Is this normal?

Tags: python, load, curses, python-curses

Im building this simple application and i noticed that while curses is running the CPU-load in "top" is 100%.. this seems bad. Can anyone explain this?

```
def Run(self, stdscr):

    self.screen = stdscr

    curs_set(0)
    self.screen.nodelay(1)
    self.y_max = self.screen.getmaxyx()[0]
    self.x_max = self.screen.getmaxyx()[1] 

    for e in self.Inv:
        self.Create_Win(self.Inv.index(e), e)

    self.test_win = self.screen.derwin(1, self.x_max, 10, 0)
    self.test_win.addstr(self.TargetDict["Target_1"]["Obj"].Name)

    running = True
    while running:
        self.screen.refresh()
        q = self.screen.getch()


        #Press q to exit program
        if q == ord("q"):
            running = False
```

### [image]

[image]

This is how the program looks while its running. As soon as i terminate the programwith 'q' it goes down to normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `getch` is not blocking, so the program is constantly cycling through the `while` loop. From the [`getch` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html):

> Get a character. Note that the integer returned does not have to be in ASCII range: function keys, keypad keys and so on return numbers higher than 256. In no-delay mode, -1 is returned if there is no input, else getch() waits until a key is pressed.

Your program sets `nodelay` prior to the loop:

```
self.screen.nodelay(1)
```

Comment: Ah i see. Yes if i turn it off the problem goes away. Seems crazy for it to eat up all the availible cpu. I remember seeing somewhere something simular that takes a time-value its waits for input before continueing the loop.. cant remember the name of it tho.. ill have to google a bit (unless you know it?)

Comment: A common pattern is for blocking functions to provide a timeout parameter, but unfortunately `getch` does not allow you to do a timeout. You could try something like http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep although that is usually not the best way to structure your code - and `sleep` is not the answer here anyway because 1 second is probably too long to wait.

Comment: The function i was thinking of was [halfdelay(tenthsofsecond)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.halfdelay) , tho i cant get that to work just now..

Comment: FWIW, you might want to be careful with `halfdelay` - especially in a tight loop - because according to the docs, it will raise an exception when it times out.

Comment: oh, thats what im getting then :P godamnit... ill have to rethink this.. without nodelay(1) i dont really understand how im supposed to have curses take input and get automatic screen updates at the same time without the cpu going haywire

Comment: `halfdelay` could work if you make the delay sufficiently long such that exceptions are not being thrown continuously (which would impact performance, or at least CPU usage), and you handle the exceptions which should be straightforward. Anyway, it's been a long time since I've worked with anything like curses and I have never used this API before, so I do not have any more specific suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: I think the best solution is to use the [window.timeout(delay_ms)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.timeout) method to set the getch input timeout in milliseconds. No exceptions to handle.

Comment: @Craig: that seems indeed the best approach, assuming that it doesn't use `halfdelay` + handling exceptions internally.

Comment: Actually, I think it serves a different purpose: isn't `timeout` the one used to differentiate an `ESC` from other key combinations? Documentation on that is very weak

Comment: you are thinking of the confusingly named `notimeout()` which disables or enables the delay waiting for the next character after the escape character

Answer (score 1):

Where nodelay(True) is needed, use built in sleep function

```
curses.napms(10)
```

at the end of the while loop, to limit your FPS.
Number is in milliseconds so 10ms, for example, should refresh the loop in 100FPS.

In my practice game this solution dropped CPU usage to almost 0%, without noticeable impact on responsiveness.